# Thales HSM 8000 A2 command sending (generate clear component)

Tags: java, command

Using Java, I'm sending an A2-command in HSM port, but receive an error.

```
Input to HSM : 0000A2002U
Output from HSM : 0000A318
```

In documentation I found that A3 - this is response  on A2 command and 18 is an error that means: Document format definition not loaded

I need to generate a clear component (not key as in A0 command). In console mode, I'm using `gc` command.

Java code:

```
System.out.println("<<< Connected to HSM  >>>:" + socket.isConnected());
in = new DataInputStream (new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
out = new DataOutputStream (new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
command = "0000A2002U";
out.writeUTF(command);
System.out.println("Input to HSM : " +command);
out.flush();
String response = in.readUTF();
System.out.println("Output from HSM : " +response);
System.out.println("");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send this data to HSM:

```
000A30303030413230303255
**** 0 0 0 0 A 2 0 0 2 U
```

Where **** represent size of data to sent in hex.

HSM return two frames:
One for command receive and other for printing information. Like this:
000000A300U9FABB20DD3BACFD81B832D918B008B4A
000000AZ00

Comment: Which data must be under `****`? Is that what I must sent to HSM: `command = "000A30303030413230303255**** 0 0 0 0 A 2 0 0 2 U"` for Clear Component generating?

Comment: In the sample above the value: 000A represent length of your data (0000A2002U).

Answer (score 0):

```
    package hsm;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TestHSMJava {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("<<< Main Method Entry >>>");

    String command = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    DataInputStream in = null;
    byte[] b= new byte[100];
    try {
        socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9998);
        System.out.println("<<< Socket >>> :" + socket);
        if (socket != null) {
           /* System.out.println("<<< Connected to HSM  >>>:"
                    + socket.isConnected());
            in = new DataInputStream (new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new DataOutputStream (new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
            command = "0006303030304e43";
            out.writeUTF(command);
            System.out.println("Input to HSM : " +command);
            out.flush();
            String response = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Output from HSM : " +response);
            System.out.println("..");*/
            System.out.println("<<< Connected to HSM  >>>:" + socket.isConnected());
            in = new DataInputStream (new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new DataOutputStream (new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
            command = "000A3030303041323030325500060000A2002U";
            out.writeUTF(command);
            System.out.println("Input to HSM : " +command);
            out.flush();
            String response = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Output from HSM : " +response);
            System.out.println("");
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    }}
```

Comment: Consider adding some context to your answer, rather than just a block of code. It will help others understand how you solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the java method writeUTF put de message length before de command.

Your command must be "3030303041323030325500060000A2002U" because writeUTF put before 000A.